# Search in current page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a code in jQuery that searches if a div tag exists with a certain class, a function should be executed.

The code works fine, but the issue is that the function is executed in every page because the div exists on the website.

Is there a way to check if the div exists on the current page or not.

This is my code

```
if($(".parent-class .div-with-certain-class")){
   /*Execute function*/
}
```

I want the function to execute only if the div-with-certain class exists on the current page.
Is it possible using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test for `length` - in jQuery you can search for `$('#this-id-does-not-exist')` and you'll get a `truthy` response, but the `length` property will be 0

```
if($(".parent-class .div-with-certain-class").length>0){
   /*Execute function*/
}
```

See for yourself here:

```js
// test for length
console.log($('#this-is-nowhere').length)
console.log($('#i-exist').length)

// vs:
console.log($('#this-is-nowhere'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='i-exist'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Some pages have the class some don't, I only want to execute on those who have the class.

Comment: Ok, I think your issue was you were testing for a truthy value which would always return TRUE. My answer shows to test for length which will be zero when there are no matches. Please accept this as the answer if that's the case. Thanks